# Ninject with InRequestScope binding returning a unique item on each call

Tags: c#, ninject, webforms

I am using Ninject in a WebForms application. I have NinjectConfiguration modules for different parts of the application.

All bindings are set to 'InRequestScope' binding. However, when running the application each call to `Kernel.Get<T>()` returns a new instance.

I am using the following code in my Global.asax:

```
public class Global : NinjectHttpApplication
{
   public static IKernel SharedKernel { get; private set; }

   protected override Ninject.IKernel CreateKernel()
   {
       SharedKernel = new StandardKernel();

       // I have added these two lines to resolve an exception about IntPtr
       SharedKernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
       SharedKernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

       SharedKernel.Load(new NinjectDataLayerConfiguration());

      return SharedKernel;
   }
}
```

My NinjectModule:

```
public class NinjectDataLayerConfiguration : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<EFContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
        Bind<IProjectRepository>().To<ProjectRepository>().InRequestScope();

        /* other repositories */
    }
}
```

And in Web.Config I've added a HttpModule to make sure that items are disposed at the end of a request:

```
<add name="OnePerRequestModule" type="Ninject.OnePerRequestModule" />
```

But when I run the following code:

```
 var ProjectRepository1 = SharedKernel.Get<IProjectRepository>();
 var ProjectRepository2 = SharedKernel.Get<IProjectRepository>();
```

I get two different instances back and this is causing all kind of errors (since I'm using Entity Framework and my ObjectContext should be shared trough the request).

Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you do not use one of the web extensions. e.g. Ninject.Web (in addition to Ninject.Web.Common) in case of WebForms

Comment: I removed all Ninject packages from my solution and then added Ninject.Web. I then noticed I had two files in my App_Start and after adding the bindings everything worked.

Comment: @WouterdeKort I'm having this same problem with my application and I've even created a fresh WebForms app and added `Ninject`, `Ninject.Web.Common` and `Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost` and still my `InRequestScope` binds are all unique.  What were the "*two* files" you had in `App_Start`?  `Ninject` has only added one to mine: `NinjectWebCommon.cs` (in old versions it used to be called `Ninject.Web.Common.cs`). Thanks

Comment: @ChrisWalsh I'm sorry, this question was from almost 8 years ago and I can't remember anymore what those two files where.

Comment: @WouterdeKort So for some reason, `InRequestScope` only works if injected using `[Inject]` attributes on public properties and not when I request services from the kernel directly. Thanks.